# Mysql get maximum value in one tuple

Tags: mysql

I make a table from row data like:

```
+----------------------+
| id | 1st | 2nd | 3th |
+----------------------+
|  0 |   1 |   3 |  2.5|
|  1 | 2.5 |   5 |    3|
|  2 |   4 | 3.5 |    0|
+----------------------+
```

And I want get this:

```
+--------------+
| id | max set | 
+--------------+
|  0 |     2nd | 
|  1 |     2nd |  
|  2 |     1st | 
+--------------+
```

How can I do?

Comment: What code have you attempted yourself? Showing us your efforts...

Comment: Use MySQL `IF()` statements in the query, something like `SELECT IF(1st > 2nd and 1st > 3rd, "1st"), IF(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `greatest()` and `field()`:

```
select id,
       field(greatest(col1, col2, col3), col1, col2, col3) as ColWithMax
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested - use CASE: 
    select lineno,
    case
    when 1st>2nd and 2nd>3rd then '1st'
    when 2nd>1st and 2nd>3rd then '2nd'
    when 3rd>1st and 3rd>2nd then '3rd'
    else 0
    end as 'MaxValue'
    from yourtable;